# Can the Unix/Linux shell be considered an Operating System in addition to a programming language?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh, dos

When comparing it to DOS it seems like it has the same functionality and more. Therefore, I was wondering if I could consider shells like Bourne shell or bash to be equivalent to DOS and consider it a type of operating system. Or are the terms are mutually exclusive?

Also is the shell interpreting all my commands into assembly language ?

If the shell is a programming language (a scripting one) then when you create programs in C, you are still executing them using commands through shell (i.e. scripted), so I would assume you are introducing a bottleneck at this point that would slightly limit the speed as opposed to having a non-scripted intermediary.

Comment: The shell is just one part of the operating system. Take away the kernel, and it does nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the defining characteristic of an OS is that it manages your hardware for you. The shell does not do this, the kernel does.

Since you brought up DOS, the shell is the equivalent of `command.com`, the command interpreter.

The "kernel" of DOS was found in the likes of `msdos.sys`, `io.sys`, `ibmdos.com` or `ibmbio.com`, depending on your flavour.

---

In terms of what the shell does, it depends on the shell, but it's unlikely it will convert your input into assembler or machine language. For example, the `bash` shell is an interpreter, plain and simple. It's a C program that reads commands and executes its own functions based on those commands.

It does not turn those commands into a lower-level language.

---

And re the bottlerneck comments, while the shell is responsible for *starting* your program, it does not slow it down while it's running. Instead, it tends to (by default) get out of the way until your program exits and then it takes over again.

Answer (score 4):

You could (in principle) run a Linux system without any shell. You would then have a specialized [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) program which would perhaps start other programs and processes using [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

Maybe even [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) is such a thing. Perhaps it might be configured to avoid any shell.

Certainly you should be able to setup a Rasberry Pi (and even a desktop PC) running Linux without any shell (but with a specific `/sbin/init`, which you could pass using e.g. the [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) bootloader to the kernel ...)

However the shell is so convenient (and `/bin/sh` is used by libc functions like [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) or [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)) that removing it is often not reasonable and should be done with care.

Perhaps some Linux appliances (routers etc...) don't need any shell, or at least don't use it. They might have a [busybox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busybox) (which is often acting as a shell) or their own `init` like program without using  shells.

You need to read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and wikipages about [syscalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall), [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29), [linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) etc...

The shell is a Linux application program (and you could write your own, it is very instructive. At least study the source code of existing free software shells like `sash` or [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)). Linux application programs see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) as elementary "atomic" operations (in fact implemented by one machine instruction like [`SYSENTER`](http://wiki.osdev.org/SYSENTER) with specific conventions, see [Assembly HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/)). Also, learn about [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and try it.

Actually, things are more complex (e.g. [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html))... BTW, you can have a Linux system made entirely of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) : don't hesitate to look into the source code!

Answer (score 3):

This question demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of how computer hardware works, what an operating system does, and what a shell is.

The standard model is (very loosely) as follows: computer hardware runs binary instructions that it loads from memory. The hardware also raises "exceptions" when various conditions are met (such as timeouts, invalid memory accesses, hardward IO, etc.). When the computer powers on, it starts running kernel code. The kernel sets up code to handle these exceptions, sets up the memory management unit and lowers the privilege level (thus restricting memory access and so on), and then calls user code. The user code then runs on the hardware until one of the exceptions is raised (typically one of the timeout exceptions, or a specific 'system call' exception that can be raised by the user code), returning control to the kernel. The kernel can thus choose which user code to run when, and can also choose what privileges  to provide to which user code.

The shell is simply a user-level program that provides a text-based interface to various useful operating system functions, such as creating files and running programs. It accomplishes these tasks in the same way as any other user-level program.

(Please note that all of the above is very approximate, and possibly inaccurate in areas, and definitely misses a lot of details, but it should still be somewhat useful to understand the basics of *how* the operating system can do what it does.)